# Optimal path between more than 23 points

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I know that google api provide a way to provide 23 way points where it optimize the route for you.

If I have more than 23 points, how can I achieve that? I can divide them into 2 groups but how do I know which 2 ones should be connected between the groups

The other way I thought about it is to find which point is the closest to me. Then determine the next closest point and so on.

I basically want to build an optimal path that connects all the points (optimal being shortest distance)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [Travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) problem. The time complexity of this problem is really huge, that's why, I think, `Google` limited number of waypoints to 23. You can check this [article](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp/tsp) to get know how to solve this problem. There are several examples written in most popular languages. 

Also, I had solved this problem before, I used [Ant colony optimization](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Ant_colony_optimization) for that. This algorithm gives you the ability to build path through ~100 waypoints for an acceptable time, but it can fail sometimes, e.g. you didn't build path at all

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was hoping I can do 2 requests to google with 23 way points but somehow know which 2 locations to connect these 23 points